# Why not display rep on CW posts?

Tags: discussion, reputation, community-wiki

After reading [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60370/why-are-there-answered-by-usernames-on-answers) (which basically suggests not displaying user info on questions and answers) I am left wondering why we don't display the usual little info box about a poster on a CW question?

I realize, of course, that there is no rep on CW posts, and that the acceptance rate is also unaffected by CW. However, if it is valid to display these metrics on normal posts, why not on CW?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User name and rep/badges not appearing are hints that...

1. Ownership is de-emphasized on wiki posts (means easier editing, less about "this is MY answer!")
2. No reputation accrues to anyone in a wiki post

Comment: +1: I'm all about UI hints.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of CW questions is to detach the author from the content.  Adding the reputation will undermine that idea.

Comment: I think the percentage of ownership shown for CW questions is very much attaching an author to the content.

Comment: @Grace that is because nothing on StackOverflow (except voting) is anonymous. There is still accountability in the form of name, but the reputation isn't added because it is meant to be community owned. For instance, if you have two posts, one 51% by "JS" with 200k reputation, and one that is 99% by "db" with 3k rep. Which is more trustworthy?

Comment: @devinb When it comes to properly utilized CW posts, I don't find trustworthiness relevant. When I look at it, adding reputation listings would attribute unnecessary *importance* to the user, but it wouldn't attach the author to the post any more than the percentage already does.

Comment: @Grace. That's a much better way of putting it. the reputation is irrelevant to CW posts.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should show the rep, I can always go to the persons profile, its just an annoying extra step.

However, if we are not going to display rep, lets at least be consistent and stop displaying rep on comments in CW posts when you hover the persons name.

Comment: OR show the persons rep on hover like the comments already do!