# Stack Overflow login system using Facebook Connect

Tags: support, openid, login, facebook

I have created my Stack Overflow account using my Google [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID). However, once I login to Stack Overflow, I am never logged out even if I log out from Gmail in a different tab. Can the same be done using an Facebook login?

I mean, even if I login using Facebook and log out from Facebook, it does not log me out from the authenticated and authorized website?

Comment: Ask this question here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: It is not actually about the stackoverflow login system. it is more about Facebook single sign-on. Should is still move it to meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Actually, this question is only using SO family sites as example. This question is about authentication systems from other websites. However, we don't have a site which is a good place to answer you. Super User is the closest, but website questions are off-topic there. The main question here is the difference between FB login, and openid from Google.

Comment: This should be on SU... though I have a feeling the answer is "No."

Comment: Possible dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29254/facebook-as-a-login-provider

Answer (score 4):

I have a feeling the answer is **No** simply because when you log out of Facebook it removes the cookies it set. When you log into a site with [Facebook Connect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Facebook_Connect) it logs you into Facebook which will set a cookie.

OpenID works differently. I believe that when you login with your OpenID (Google being the example) the site (Stack Overflow, Server Fault, etc.) sets its own cookie. That's how you can be logged in to Super User but not Meta Stack Overflow.