# Possible positive effects of VC funding for Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, subjective, business-model

Relating to [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39545/possible-negative-effects-of-vc-funding-for-stackoverflow), what are the possible positive effects of venture capital funding for Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 13):

Localization becomes a priority.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: The StackExchange is not localizable at the moment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4169/any-progress-in-se-localization VC funding may provide for the necessary resources to speed up the process.

Comment: @Pekka: thanks, that makes sense (now)!

Comment: Stack Overflow != Stack Exchange. See my answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39539/would-you-take-a-share-in-stack-overflow/39542#39542 Joel indicated they may sell Stack Exchange back to Stack Overflow LLC one day. Right now, they're two separate companies. I'm talking about localization for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @George I would assume localizing SO and SE will be if not the same, then at least very, very similar beasts.

Comment: @Pekka Keep in mind that Stack Exchange has a more 'generic' model than Stack Overflow does. It will be similar, but Stack Exchange has to deal with being localizable and generic, Stack Overflow is highly optimized for its audience and thus has a bit of a different set of criteria for localization.

Comment: @George I'd expect that this would creep back up into the SO code eventually.  It's not a benefit for me, but I can see it helping some.

Comment: @George I was thinking more along the lines of localized versions of SO for non-english audiences, for which I believe there is a large number of people who are at this moment outside SO's scope. I don't know whether this is a priority in where Joel and Jeff what to go with the VC funding, but it would be interesting IMO.

Answer (score 8):

They can afford to provide every 10K+ user their choice of pony, unicorn, waffles or being Jon Skeet for a day.

Comment: Sign me up for a year-supply of waffles.

Comment: With enough VC funds, all things are possible. :)

Comment: I would prefer a Pegasus with the horn of a unicorn.

Answer (score 7):

They will be able to afford to build a [mobile version of StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so).

Comment: Given the capabilities of modern mobile browsers, the current sites are almost 'mobile friendly'. I've been browsing with a few mobile browsers (incl. Opera mini/mobile), I would say the main issue is the layout which requires lots of scrolling.

Comment: @okw, I tried Opera mini but haven't got it to access SO yet, just an error page.

Comment: @okw it's not too bad on my iPod Touch, but there's definitely some room for improvement.  I can't imagine ever using a mobile app to answer or ask questions (too much typing), but it would be useful for searching and for tracking updates/votes through the day as I'm away from my desk.

Comment: @Joel, I've actually typed codes using alphanumeric keypads to post answers. Painful but I was real bored then. :P

Answer (score 7):

- They'd hire a real server admin, rather than needing developers standing in as server admins.  Not that the team has done a bad job, but there have been some avoidable outages.
- A development database that doesn't live on the production server.
- Connections needed to force advertisers to give SO a second look who currently pass it over because they don't allow animated/flash ads.  It'd be nice to see some of the ad dollars from the VS2010 launch campaign make it's way to SO, for example.
- Money to promote serverfault a little better.
- More user profile customization

Finally, if they really want to "raise the level of discourse on the entire internet", they're gonna have to compete with phpBB on price at some point.  And that means a version that can be hosted on a php server.  And that means a re-write, or at least parallel implementation.  I don't think mono will cut it for that crowd.  I'm skeptical of the idea that php hosts are really cheaper in a meaningful way (I can find asp.net hosting for $5/mo, just like php - or even free from time to time), but the perception exists.