# How can I invest in Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, company

How I can invest in Stack Exchange Inc. and in the idea behind the Stack Exchange? Maybe in form of shares?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39539/would-you-take-a-share-in-stack-overflow

Comment: The company is still privately held so the answer of Joel is valid.

Comment: also relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79435/what-is-stack-overflows-business-model

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stack Exchange Inc. isn't publicly traded, but there have been four series of investments in the past by institutional investors, as indicated on the [company page](https://stackoverflow.com/company/). So unless you are a professional investor with a **lot** of money, I think you have to wait to the [initial public offering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_public_offering), if it ever will happen. Not all companies will pass that stage.